# Angular - View isn't updated when I change data of my model

Tags: angular

I have the code in my page

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let arquivo of arquivos">
          <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title>{{ arquivo?.nome }}</mat-card-title>
          </mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-content>
            {{ arquivo?.texto }}
          </mat-card-content>
          <mat-card-footer>
            <a href="{{ arquivo?.link }}"> {{ arquivo?.link }} </a>
          </mat-card-footer>
        </mat-card>
```

In my component, the code is:

```
 callMethod(): void {
    console.log('cheguei realizarPesquisa ');
    this.texto = this.pesquisaForm.value.filtro;

    this.adminService.loadArquivosbyTexto(this.texto).subscribe((arquivos) => {
      this.arquivos = arquivos;
      //this.cd.detectChanges();
    });
```

However, my page is only updated when I enable the line (`this.cd.detectChanges();`).
The return of the backend is ok and delay around 20 seconds. But even I return anything else immediately doesn't work.

I already made code like this several times, but this time isn't working.

Added this line: `this.cd.detectChanges();`

Comment: Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5211833)

Comment: check this link about [ChangeDetection.OnPush](https://mokkapps.de/blog/the-last-guide-for-angular-change-detection-you-will-ever-need/)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend if possible to not manually subscribe on an Observable.
Angular has an async pipe that handles all te logic for you.

so try this:

```
 arquivos : Observable<ArquivoTYPE>

 callMethod(): void {
    this.texto = this.pesquisaForm.value.filtro;

    //assigning the entire observable to the field
    this.arquivos = this.adminService.loadArquivosbyTexto(this.texto);
```

And in your html you use the **async** pipe

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let arquivo of (arquivos| async)">
   <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>{{ arquivo?.nome }}</mat-card-title>
   </mat-card-header>
   <mat-card-content>
      {{ arquivo?.texto }}
   </mat-card-content>
   <mat-card-footer>
      <a href="{{ arquivo?.link }}"> {{ arquivo?.link }} </a>
   </mat-card-footer>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: Good, it works now, thanks. A last question, How can I fire multiple methods after this.arquivos be updated with this code?


 `this.arquivos = this.adminService.loadArquivosbyTexto(this.texto);`

Here I can

`this.adminService.loadArquivosbyTexto(this.texto).subscribe((arquivos) => {
      this.arquivos = arquivos;
      console.log('------------- ' + this.arquivos);
    });
`

Comment: can you give an example because I don't understand?

Comment: When this.arquivos updated, I would like call console.log() by example, how can I do this?

In the earlier form, I can call other methods inside method subscribe

Comment: you can use rxjs operators to **tap** your Observable like this `this.arquivos.pipe(
  tap(console.log))`